# How to configure multiple jump with single Proxycommand

Tags: ssh

I have `~/.ssh/config` file as

```
Host head
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xx.xxx.xx

Host machine1
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xx1.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null

Host machine2
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xx2.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null

Host machine3
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xx3.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null

Host machine4
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xx4.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

but manually set more machines would be tedious, how can I set one instance such as

```
Host machine*
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xx*.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

as the HostName address only differs in a number.

**UPDATE** following Tagwint't suggession, I get :

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: You can have: `Host machine*` + User and IdentifyFile and ProxyCommand as they are the same for all cases, and then just some specific `Host machine1` with the needed `HostName`, repeated per machine. Also why do you really need to put the IP addresses of the host in your configuration? Without this requirement you solve your problem as all configurations share the same all three User/IdentityFile/ProxyCommand

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thank you, can you give some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `ProxyJump` command:

```
Host machine1 machine2 machine3
  ProxyJump head
```

You can do a double hop through two hosts if needed, like this:

```
Host machine1 machine2 machine3
  ProxyJump head,jump
```

Or match everything in a domain like this:

```
Match host "*.example.com" 
  ProxyJump head,jump
```

You can even do it depending on your current IP address:

```
Match host "*.example.com" !exec "ifconfig | grep -q ' 172.16.1.40 '"
  ProxyJump head,jump.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange dns resolving like

```
xxx.xx1.xxx.xx machine1
xxx.xx2.xxx.xx machine2
xxx.xx3.xxx.xx machine3
```

(either with DNS server config, or with entries in /etc/hosts file)

Then your last instance in .ssh/config will w/o Hostname entry
cover them all:

```
Host machine*
  User Marry
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tagwint, but I get an error, pls see my update